# Cannot connect to the Azure SQL Server using ad admin account

Tags: sql-server, azure, sql-server-2012, azure-sql-database

I have created an Azure SQL Server and assigned an ad administrator to it using terraform

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "server" {
  name                         = "adauth-sqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "faadmin"
  administrator_login_password = "faadmin-password"

  azuread_administrator {
    login_username = "SP-NCS-CREATED-FOR-DB"
    tenant_id = "12345fd6-1234-4871-a542-eb12a5a7800c"
    object_id = "d2db88ce-1234-1234-8d93-b256be13bd27"
  }
  public_network_access_enabled = true
  azure_ad_authentication_only = false
}
```

The administrator is a Service Principal. I can see in the portal and also query it

```
PS C:\SqlServerAADAuthenitcation> az sql server ad-admin list --resource-group databaseadauthRG --server-name adauth-sqlserver
[
  {
    "administratorType": "ActiveDirectory",
    "azureAdOnlyAuthentication": false,
    "id": "/subscriptions/1e27b63d-d44b-478e-afe9-08e5bf46eb7f/resourceGroups/databaseadauthRG/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/adauth-sqlserver/administrators/ActiveDirectory",
    "login": "SP-NCS-CREATED-FOR-DB",
    "name": "ActiveDirectory",
    "resourceGroup": "databaseadauthRG",
    "sid": "d2db88ce-1234-1234-8d93-b256be13bd27",
    "tenantId": "12345fd6-1234-4871-a542-eb12a5a7800c",
    "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers"
  }
]
```

When I try to connect to the server using 'Active Directory Password' authentication, it throws an error.
Another test fails with the error Login failed for user token-identified principal.

How is one supposed to connect to an azure ad admin user so that to be able to add more acive directory users and groups

I have read this a couple of time.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities

Thanks in advance for anyone who looks into this.

Comment: Firstly I would check in the Azure portal whether the AAD user has actually stuck. I'm just about to experiment whether service principals actually work as SQL Administrators right now. How are you connecting via 'Active Directory Password' authentication_. Through a client tool or through some kind if automation? Typically I wouldn't expect you to be able to connect with service principal credentials from an interactive client tool.

Comment: Also, have you configured the firewall rules to allow the IP address of the computer from where you are connecting to your SQL database?

Comment: _Login failed for user token-identified principal._ is an authorisation error, meaning that network is not the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Nick.McDermaid. I have configured network, after initially receiving error. I am using SSMS to test ad-administrator login. I can connect using faadmin, the non ad azure sql administrator, but it cannot add ad users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I try to connect to the server using 'Active Directory Password' authentication, it throws an error. Another test fails with the error Login failed for user token-identified principal.

Thanks to `Nick.McDermaid` for suggesting the same.

It is not possible to log in to the Azure SQL server via GUI when using a service principal. Service principals are intended for automation purposes only, and you cannot use any UI tools to authenticate with Azure SQL using service principal credentials.

To create Azure SQL with Azure AD authentication, you can follow the below Terraform code.

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "rg-name" {
  name     = "rg-name"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_mssql_server" "samplesql" {
  name                         = "mssqlserverdemotest"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.venkat-rg.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.venkat-rg.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "missadministrator"
  administrator_login_password = ""
  minimum_tls_version          = "1.2"

  azuread_administrator {
    login_username = "<user principal name>"
    object_id      = "<user principal object ID>"
  }
}
```

I logged into Azure Sql DB with azure AD user as below.

[image]

**Note:** Make sure to you use [user principal name and object ID](https://i.imgur.com/LiOeOew.png)

References:

1. [Azure SQL database using service principal | Thomas Thornton](https://thomasthornton.cloud/2020/10/06/query-azure-sql-database-using-service-principal-with-powershell/)

Comment: I will accept this answer. I have gone through the referenced article as well. Wanted to validate with my Visual Studio Enterprise subscription. Does the ad administrator need to added to the database as a user?  I keep getting connection failure for <token identified user>. Does this mean that the database identity needed to be allowed Read All access in the active directory

Comment: @Tauqir - When I tried, my ad user had a contributor role. Check the access for your user. provide the minimum role of SQL server Contributor and verify whether it is working.